# Powershell GUI - not calling sub batch file

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file, gui

**Regarding my Powershell script with GUI:** 
 When compiled as a `.exe` (PS2GUI with noConsole) it works properly, but when calling this same `.exe` from a `.bat`, it does not work:

- It does not start the `Start-Process` batch file below; the problem is that I cannot call the `.exe` file directly from an Eclipse-based launcher, which is why we need a `.bat` for it to be launched.
- I have tried `start script.exe` in a `.bat`
- I have tried calling the `.ps1` directly, however the refresh timer does not work and the checking of if the application & sub-batch files are already running is also not working.

How do I make these things work properly?

**Powershell script:**

```powershell
#Date format for Logfile
$heute        = Get-Date -UFormat %d_%m_%Y_%R
$LogFile      = "c:\temp\output.txt"
$TempLocation = "c:\temp\startscript"

#Kill already started startscript
Get-Process -Name noconsole_exe | where { $_.Id -ne $PID } | Stop-Process

#Kill already started project.bat
$fltr = "name like '%cmd.exe%' and commandline like '%project.bat%'"
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter $fltr).Terminate()

# Percentage
Function get-count {
  $Percent.text = (gci $TempLocation).count * 10
  $form.refresh()
}

$timer1           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer1.Enabled   = $true
$timer1.Start()
$timer1.Interval  = 100

#form
$timer1.add_tick({get-count})

#GUI Form
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                           = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                = '600,200'
$Form.text                      = "Start"
$Form.BackColor                 = "#ffffff"
$Form.TopMost                   = $false
$Form.startposition             = "centerscreen"
$Form.icon                      = "c:\startscripts\startscript.ico"

$Label1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                    = "Program is starting, please wait."
$Label1.AutoSize                = $true
$Label1.width                   = 25
$Label1.height                  = 10
$Label1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(131,28)
$Label1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,16'

$Label2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text                    = "Please include the log below"
$Label2.AutoSize                = $true
$Label2.width                   = 25
$Label2.height                  = 10
$Label2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,109)
$Label2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ToolTip1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
$ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle          = "Log File Location: c:\temp\output.txt"

$Button2                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.text                   = "Send Log via E-Mail"
$Button2.width                  = 173
$Button2.height                 = 30
$Button2.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210,142)
$Button2.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ToolTip2                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
$ToolTip2.ToolTipTitle          = "Send Log via E-Mail"

$Label3                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label3.text                    = "%"
$Label3.AutoSize                = $true
$Label3.width                   = 25
$Label3.height                  = 10
$Label3.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(317,61)
$Label3.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,16'

$Percent                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Percent.Text                   = (gci $TempLocation).count * 10
$Percent.AutoSize               = $true
$Percent.width                  = 30
$Percent.height                 = 12
$Percent.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(276,61)
$Percent.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,16'

$ToolTip2.SetToolTip($Button2,'Opens Outlook with the log file. Please include also a screenshot of an error message and send the e-mail.')
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2,$Button2,$Label3,$Percent))

$Button2.Add_Click({ OpenMailLog })

function OpenLog { Start-Process notepad $LogFile }

function append-text {
  process{
    foreach-object {$_ + "%0d%0a"}
  }
}

function OpenMailLog {
  Copy-Item "c:\temp\output.txt" -Destination "c:\temp\output_4_mail.txt"

  $MailText = Get-Content -path "c:\temp\output.txt"
  $MailText | append-text | out-file "c:\temp\output_4_mail.txt"
  $AntiText = Get-Content -path "c:\temp\output_4_mail.txt"

  $Output = @()

  #Add new text
  $Output += "Dear Mr.X,%0d%0ahere is the log file output.%0d%0a%0d%0a"

  #Append old text from content
  $Output += $AntiText
  $Output | Out-file "c:\temp\output_4_mail.txt"
  $BodyText = Get-Content -path "c:\temp\output_4_mail.txt"
  Start-Process "mailto:example@acme.com?Subject=Log file&Body=$BodyText"
}

Start-Process -FilePath "c:\startscripts\project.bat" -RedirectStandardOutput "$LogFile" -WindowStyle Hidden
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I don't think you can call script files by using start-process. But I bet that if you use `cmd /c "c:\startscripts\project.bat" it will work`.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
$heute = Get-Date -UFormat %d_%m_%Y_%R
```

... is never used anywhere in your code, so why declare it.

Running external command via PowerShell must follow a prescribed implementation. As documented below:

Using PowerShell and external commands and their parameters or switches.

• [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

• [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)

• [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)

• [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)

• Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right

> ```
> https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right
>
> https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/execution-of-external-commands-native-applications-in-powershell-done-right-part-2
>
> https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/execution-of-external-commands-native-applications-in-powershell-done-right-part-3
>
> http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right
> ```

• Quoating specifics

> ```
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules
>
> https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting
> ```

***So, this line...***

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\startscripts\project.bat" -RedirectStandardOutput "$LogFile" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

***... should be something like this...***

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-Command &{ d:\temp\abc.bat }' -RedirectStandardOutput $LogFile -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Or what LPChip, is suggesting, but this method to get this logged you'd have to use the redirect as noted here:

[about_Redirection - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however it does not work - I am getting the same issue as before - with your Start-Process line & the cmd /c method. Using the Process Explorer I see that the compiled .exe is running (as a subprocess from an Eclipse launcher process, but my compiled .exe does not start the c:\startscripts\project.bat. Running the .exe by double clicking it on the other hand has always worked.

Comment: My answer works as written. However, I am not an Eclipse person, do not have loaded because I have no need for it in my day to day workload. So, no way of digging at that. Point of note: and code block that is passing or expecting to pass anything on the pipeline, must be written to allow that. Nothing in the code you posted shows that you are doing that at all. ['pipeline function PowerShell'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=pipeline+function+powershell&form=ANNTH1&refig=1e1344fad3354d59ab599e9e97445846&sp=1&qs=AS&pq=pipeline+function&sk=PRES1&sc=6-17&cvid=1e1344fad3354d59ab599e9e97445846).

Comment: Double-clicking is not passing anything, thus it should work.

Comment: tried to do both - what LPChip was suggesting & your approach. It did not work on both... Maybe there is an issue with PS2EXE GUI? I have been using the -nooutput -noconsole and -noError options... But I tested various ones, none of them show an expected result...